# Importing sub module of FFmpeg in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I was able to import the "full" module of FFmpeg library in Android like this:

```
api 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full:6.0-2'
```

But this was adding about 90mb to my app. So I tried to import only "min-gpl" like

```
api 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:6.0-2'
```

But instead of decreasing, this actually increased my app size further (about 100mb).

Am I not doing it right?